# How to read Long from DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to access a DynamoDB table from a Java application where the key is a long integer. Reading this guide, https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html, it seems that I can cast my N (number in table) as Long or BigInteger. When I try to retrieve data in both cases, I get this exception:

```
2023-01-21T17:28:49.970+01:00 ERROR 15940 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: SensorData[sample_time]; could not unconvert attribute] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object, Object[])" because "this.setter" is null
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$MethodReflect.set(StandardBeanProperties.java:133) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.set(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:111) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.unconvertAndSet(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:164) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.unconvert(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:267) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.privateMarshallIntoObject(DynamoDBMapper.java:472) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.marshallIntoObjects(DynamoDBMapper.java:500) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.PaginatedScanList.<init>(PaginatedScanList.java:64) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.scan(DynamoDBMapper.java:1571) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.scan(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:236) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.steeve.test.SensorDataRepository.getAll(SensorDataRepository.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.steeve.test.TestApplication.health(TestApplication.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1010) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:902) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

The exception is the same for Long and BigInteger. If I map the value as Integer the exception is different, it fails when it tries to do Integer.parseInt() with a too long number:

```
2023-01-21T17:35:08.136+01:00 ERROR 5064 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: SensorData[sample_time]; could not unconvert attribute] with root cause

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1674256283832"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:999) ~[na:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardTypeConverters$ToInteger$2.convert(StandardTypeConverters.java:773) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardTypeConverters$ToInteger$2.convert(StandardTypeConverters.java:770) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardTypeConverters$1.unconvert(StandardTypeConverters.java:75) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverter$DelegateConverter.unconvert(DynamoDBTypeConverter.java:109) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverter$NullSafeConverter.unconvert(DynamoDBTypeConverter.java:128) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverter$ExtendedConverter.unconvert(DynamoDBTypeConverter.java:88) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.unconvert(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:146) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.unconvertAndSet(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:164) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.unconvert(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:267) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.privateMarshallIntoObject(DynamoDBMapper.java:472) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.marshallIntoObjects(DynamoDBMapper.java:500) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.PaginatedScanList.<init>(PaginatedScanList.java:64) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.scan(DynamoDBMapper.java:1571) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.scan(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:236) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.388.jar:na]
    at com.steeve.test.SensorDataRepository.getAll(SensorDataRepository.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
```

This is my mapping class:

```java
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "sensor_data")
public class SensorData {
    
    private Long sample_time;
    
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "sample_time")
    public Long getSampletime()
    {return sample_time;}
    public void setSampleTime(Long sample_time)
    { this.sample_time = sample_time;}
    
    @DynamoDBDocument()
    public static class device_data {
        private String sensorName;
        private Float sensorValue;
        
        public void setSensorName(String sensorName)
        {this.sensorName = sensorName;}
        @DynamoDBAttribute
        public String getSensorName()
        {return this.sensorName;}
        
        public void setSensorValue(Float sensorValue)
        {this.sensorValue = sensorValue;}
        @DynamoDBAttribute
        public Float getSensorValue()
        {return this.sensorValue;}
    }
}
```

Version of AWS SDK library:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.388</version>
</dependency>
```

This makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error,the error log shows `this.setter = null`.
Try to resolve by placing the setters for all properties of the Class.
Since I don't have the Class code to analyze, it could be that

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).